# Memory problem on usage of gdb eval (malloc issue)

Tags: debugging, gdb, malloc, eval

I am trying to build a script on arm-none-eabi-gdb 
Whithin a loop of my script I am using eval command
After almost 200 loops I get this error:

> No memory available to program: call to malloc failed

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Whithin a loop of my script I am using eval command After almost 200 loops I get this error:

The `eval` command you are using is causing GDB to allocate memory in the inferior program (and likely doesn't free that memory).

Eventually, the program runs out of memory, and GDB can't perform the eval any more.

Consider what would happen if you `eval "print/x %p\n", malloc(1000000)` in a loop.

Comment: Hi Employed Russian. This is obviously the case but I am asking if there is any other way to perform this eval. Maybe something like free the memory allocated or expand the memory.

Comment: @kostas: "is there any other way to perform this eval" -- maybe. You'll need to provide a lot more details on what "this eval" is.